# Error en prototipo de number Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
Number.prototype.sq = (n) => return Math.sqrt(this);


var b = sq(5);

console.log(b);
```

***La idea de mi código es que me devuelva la raiz cuadrada de este, pero lanza error, por que?***

Comment: Falta indicar que es lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el tema. Referencia [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que funcione primero tienes que quitar el `this` de tu función lambda ya que está haciendo referencia a la función anónima y no al número que le estás pasando como argumento, en su lugar pon la `n` que es su argumento.

Cuando tu creas una función con prototype, le estás agregando funcionalidad a la clase (por llamarla de algún modo), entonces para acceder a esa función tienes que crear una instancia de la clase, en tu caso una instancia de Number

```
var b=new Number();
```

Quedaría así

```js
Number.prototype.sq = (n) => Math.sqrt(n);

var b=new Number();

console.log(b.sq(5) );
```

Si quieres evitar crear una instancia, puedes crear una función de clase

```js
Number.sq = (n) => Math.sqrt(n); //Sin prototype

var b = Number.sq(5);

console.log(b);
```

Aquí podras entender mejor [como funcionan los prototipos](http://www.programania.net/diseno-de-software/entendiendo-los-prototipos-en-javascript/)

Comment: esta respuesta es peligrosa estas reescribiendo la clase Number de Javascript si haces esto te dara problemas con otras librerias

Comment: La respuesta es en base a lo que se preguntó.
La clase no se reescribe, se le está agregando funcionalidad.

Comment: tiene razon pero es la forma que se construye que es extraño; si usas b.toFixed() te devuelve null obviamente no hay ningun valor(aplica para el primer caso), en el segundo lo asignas de una vez y no va a ver problemas

Comment: Es correcto, para que funciones `toFixed()` tendría que tener un valor el Number por ejemplo `var b=8.123456` y la línea `console.log(b.sq(5) );`  seguiría teniendo el mismo resultado **2.236....**, probablemente no tenga sentido para nosotros por eso sugerí `Number.sq = (n) =>`, aunque no sabesmos la finalidad del desarrollo. Sin embargo hacer los prototipos es muy util cuando haces tus librerías

Answer (score 2):

He cambiado ligeramente tu función para que no de ningún problema.

Anteriormente, no le estabas asignando la función a ninguna variable que fuera número.

```js
Number.prototype.sq = function() {
    return Math.sqrt(this);
};

var numero = 5;
var b = numero.sq();

console.log(b);
```

Comment: Por que no como es6?

Comment: @EduardoSebastian Según vi hace un tiempo en esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41194904/equivalent-of-prototype-in-es6) de Stackoverflow, en ES6 las clases con sus métodos hacen la función de `prototype`.

Comment: Aqui se esta extendiendo una clase a traves de su prototype, no se esta creando una. Por lo que la unica forma de hacerlo es asi

Answer (score 0):

La forma correcta de lo que quieres con **ECMAScript 6** es de la siguiente forma

```js
class Numero {
    constructor(numero) {
        this.numero = numero;
    }
    sq(){
      return Math.sqrt(this.numero);
    }
    
}

var miNumero = new Numero(6);
console.log(miNumero.sq());
```

lo que quieres hacer tu es un hibrido de **ECMAScript 5** y **ECMAScript 6** la forma de hacerlo con ECMAScript 5 es de la siguiente

```js
var Numeros = function (numero) {
    this.numero = numero;
};
Numeros.prototype.sq = function () {
    return  Math.sqrt(this.numero);

};
let miNum = new Numeros(5);
console.log(miNum.sq());
```

puedes ver mas documentacion en http://es6-features.org/#ClassDefinition